# Python version and Tcl/Tk compatibility

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have installed Tcl and Tk, and I am running into the oh-so-familiar "No module named _tkinter" error.

My 'python' Bash command runs Python version 2.4.2, but [Synaptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_Package_Manager) says I have 2.6.6 installed. I even tried installing 3.0, but that also failed.

I have configured and built the Tcl/Tk tarballs myself, and tried using the synaptic packages.

Both "wish" and "tclsh" commands work, so I know that the modules are installed, but I can't for the life of me get Python to recognize them. Moreover, I can't for the life of my figure out which version of Python I should be using and how to get my Bash command to use that one.

I don't see any options for 2.4.2 removal, and if I remove 2.6.6, it removes what seems to be most of my other packages (exaggeration, I know).

I really don't know where to go from here, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

#### Update:

I had to reinstall the python-tk package, and 2.6 is able to import it. Now I just need to figure out how to remove 2.4 for the sake of not screwing something up later on.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few commands which could help you diagnose your problem.

First, try to run the `python` command with the version number appended. Since
Synaptic says you have 2.6.6 installed you should be able to run `python2.6` to
get that version:

```
(type 'python' and hit TAB to see possible completions)

% python<tab>
python
python2.6
python3.1
```

If you still can't get TK to run, find where the `_tkinter.so` module lives on 
your system.  It may be somewhere the 2.6.6 interpreter can't find it.  Here's the location as installed by `python-tk` package on Ubuntu Lucid:

```
% find /usr -name '_tkinter*'
/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for those who land on this page, regarding Python 3+ (like I have). To run `tkinter` on a Debian-based Linux (Ubuntu), `python3` is needed, as well as `python3-tk` (it's not in the library list):

```
sudo apt-get install python3
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Also, the script needs to have this as the first line:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
```

At least that is how I solved the problem.